# Is Windows Forms Secure Enough To Create a Locked Screen App Based on a USB Dongle Access

Tags: windows, winforms, security, lockscreen

I have been asked to create an application that has a password and username based screen. The idea is that it has a USB key and matching bluetooth fob. When you walk away from the computer it will lock your screen and show the password and username login screen if the USB bluetooth is not communicating with the fob. If you show back up they exchange security keys and the screen unlocks so you can get back to work. However in my readings I see buzz about the lock screen can be overridden with key presses like alt + delete etc. I did web searches on using WinForms for the UI, very simple implementation, but am not sure about WinForm security and what libraries I should be looking at to ensure that this application cannot be overridden with key presses or other similar monkey business. The software on the USB will be written in Python so I know I can communicate with it through NamedPipe. What advantages can I seek and what pitfalls should I be aware of? Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Do not implement a custom screen lock.** Use the Windows lock screen and implement an authentication provider that integrates into Windows. This is the only secure solution.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly I should not be creating a username and password with a login button UI but when they walk away but just use the Widows lock screen and integrate an authentication scheme between the USB key code and an authentication class I create that will auto-log them back in?